# Unable to edit/add `custom-tags` via the Azure DataBricks `/clusters` REST API

Tags: rest, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-rest-api

I'm trying to update cluster `custom_tags` using the DataBricks API found [here](https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/clusters/edit). The error message I receive does not match the `Required` parameters shown in the docs (`cluster_id` and `spark_version` are the only `Required` params).

**Request:**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://databricks.com/api/2.0/clusters/edit' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
      "cluster_id": 1234567,
      "cluster_version": "10.4.x-scala2.12",
      "custom_tags": {
          "TEST": "TEST"
      }
}'
```

**Response: Status 400**:

```
{
    "error_code": "INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE",
    "message": "Exactly 1 of virtual_cluster_size, num_workers or autoscale must be specified.",
    "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
          "reason": "CM_API_ERROR_SOURCE_CALLER_ERROR",
          "domain": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**EDIT 1**: Got it working though quite cumbersome.

Thank you @JayashankarGS.

1. `autoscale min_workers and max_workers` are required though not clearly documented.
2. `node_type_id` is required though undocumented
3. Be sure to parse and add any existing `custom_tags` to the `/edit` request. Otherwise they will be lost as the `/edit` `custom_tags` action **overwrites** the existing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide required fields in json.
In documentation the given required fields are `cluster_id`,`spark_version` and
autoscale - `min_workers,max_workers` or `num_workers`.

Even after adding this fields it ask some of the fields required like `node_type_id`.

Try below code.

```
curl -X POST "https://databricks_host/api/2.0/clusters/edit" -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"cluster_name": "jgs","cluster_id": "cluster_id", "custom_tags": {"TEST": "TEST"}, "spark_version": "13.3.x-scala2.12","num_workers":2,"node_type_id":"Standard_DS3_v2"}'
```

Output:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the write-up. The docs I'm looking at [here](https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/clusters/edit) show the word "required" listed 4 times. For `spark_version`, `cluster_id` and **only if `auto_scale` is used**, `min_workers` and `max_workers`. Since I'm not affecting the `auto_scale` setting (only `custom_tags`) and since the `auto_scale` value is not returned from the Clusters `/list` request, I can't use it. `num_workers` is returned from `/list` so I'll try adding that. If this fixes the issue, the docs need to be updated to show `num_workers` as `required`.

Comment: Yes. This requirements may be raised when some cluster configuration added.

Comment: Hm. This is proving to be problematic. `num_workers` isn't available in some `/list` Cluster results. Looks like I'll need to parse the `autoscale min/max_workers` values and add them to the request to update `custom_tags`. Its unclear to me why these `autoscale` values are `required` for such an edit...

Comment: indeed `node_type_id` is also an required field (undocumented). Adding it along with `autoscale min/max_workers` did allow me to **overwrite** all the `custom_tags`. **Caution**: You would also need to **parse and add** any existing `custom_tags` to your `/edit` request otherwise they will be lost.

Comment: Yeah. That's an caution need to get current tags and add it along with new tags while editing.Thanks for the information.